# No test assemblies found matching the pattern: **\*.Test.dll in build pipeline task

Tags: build, azure-pipelines, vstest

I've looked at other answers and they don't seem to be working for me.
My build works fine and I can find *.Test.dll files located under the agent's _work/2/s folder (several folders deep) where the source is located. However the VSTest task is adamant that it cannot find them. **/*.Test.dll should locate them, being a recursive search but it does not.

Using latest on-premise Azure DevOps server 2019.

Any ideas why this use of **/*.Test.dll fails?

[image: Pipeline extract]

[image: VSTest output]

This shows there are at least 4 dlls (8 is due to \bin\ and \obj)

[image: Search for Test DLLs]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `|` to define the test file paths in multiple lines.  The `testAssemblyVer2` field should like below:

```
testAssemblyVer2: |
  **\*.Test.dll
  !**\*TestAdapter.dll
  !**\obj\**
```

See the document of [Visual Studio Test task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/vstest?view=azure-devops).

Comment: This actually fixed the problem. It seems the template that created the original VSTest section adds those filters surrounded by single quotes which wasn't working. Using the non-quoted version above fixed the issue, locating all of the test libraries.

Comment: where does it say we need to use the pipe character? I could not find it